# How can the Heisenberg uncertainty inequality be defined in the unordered complex field $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, complex-numbers

The generalized uncertainty principle says,

$$\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2~ \ge ~\frac14\langle i[A, B]\rangle^2.$$

But the complex field is not ordered, i.e, inequalities like $\le$, $\ge$, etc are absurd. For instance, is $i>1$? Doesn't $i$ in there makes the whole inequation meaningless?

Comment: The commutator has its own factor of $i$

Comment: The more familiar, equivalent, formula is $\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2~ \ge ~\frac14|\langle i[A, B]\rangle|^2.$. The absolute value arises form Cauchy-Schwartz' inequality...The factor $i$ can be therefore omitted as it shows up in the absolute value. Alternatively (J.Murray's answer below), as $i[A,B]$ is real you can keep it, dropping the absolute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on Yuzuriha's comment, if $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operators, then

$$\langle [A,B]\rangle = \langle\psi,AB\psi\rangle - \langle\psi,BA\psi\rangle = \langle A \psi,B\psi\rangle - \langle B\psi,A\psi\rangle$$

but

$$\overline{\langle [A,B]\rangle} = \overline{\langle A \psi,B\psi\rangle} - \overline{\langle B\psi,A\psi\rangle} = \langle B\psi,A\psi\rangle -\langle A \psi,B\psi\rangle = -\langle [A,B]\rangle $$

which implies that $\langle [A,B]\rangle$ is purely imaginary.  The explicit factor of $i$ makes the whole thing make sense.

---

Of course, if you're in the mood for mindless pedantry, then complex numbers $z$ with $Im(z)=0$ are still complex numbers and therefore are members of an unordered set; in that case, you can define the obvious total order on the subset $R:=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | Im(z)=0\}$ and note that the objects in question belong to $R$.

Comment: The step $\langle\psi,AB\psi\rangle - \langle\psi,BA\psi\rangle = \langle A \psi,B\psi\rangle - \langle B\psi,A\psi\rangle$ is true only for Hermitian operators. What about non-Hermitian observables?

Comment: All observables are Hermitian.

Comment: In fact, all observables are self-adjoint, which is a subtly stronger requirement.

Answer (score 0):

During the proof, after using the Schwarz inequality
$$\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2\ge|\langle f|g\rangle|^2$$
We invoke the fact that, for any complex number $z$, we have:
$$|z|^2=[\mathrm{Re}(z)]^2+[\mathrm{Im}(z)]^2\ge [\mathrm{Im}(z)]^2=\left[\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}(z-z^*)\right]^2$$
From here it will be obvious that for any $z = a+\mathrm i b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real), we have
$$z-z^*=(a+\mathrm i b)-(a-\mathrm i b)=\mathrm i 2b$$
which is purely imaginary, and it will be factored out by the $\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}$ term.

So it is $i$ that makes the whole inequation meaningful.

Comment: This answer could serve as a more straightforward version of Murray's answer.